# How to shift N times last element of the list on top

Tags: java, arrays

I got array of ints, and I want in order to last element of this array will be shift on top N times, something like this:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

And now, last element will be shifted for example 3 times, and it should be expected result:

```
3, 4, 5, 1, 2
```

I tried like this:

```
int[] tab = new int[5];
tab[0] = 1;
tab[1] = 2;
tab[2] = 4;
tab[3] = 5;
tab[4] = 6;

int[] secondTab = new int[5];
int N = 3;
int j = 0;

for (int i=0; i<tab.length-1; i++){
    secondTab[i] = tab[(tab.length-1)-N];
    N--;
    if (secondTab[i+1]==0){
        secondTab[i+1] = tab[j];
    }
}
```

It's obviously bad code, j is not getting increment at all so it works only for this example, but I'm wondering what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to shift right `N` times, it means the element at the `i`-th position will be at the `(i+N)%tab.lenth`-th position:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    secondTab[(i+N)%tab.length] = tab[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shift the elements in the original array you can try something like this :

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int nbShift = 1; // the number of desired shift
for(int i = -1; i < nbShift; i++){
    int f = array[0];
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length -1 ; j++){
        array[j] = array[j + 1]; 
    }
    array[array.length - 1] = f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int[] test = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    shiftNTimes(test, 2);

    for (final int i : test) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static void shiftNTimes(int[] array, int numShifts) {

    int timesShifted = 0;
    while (timesShifted < numShifts) {
        final int temp = array[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < (array.length - 1); i++) {
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
        }

        array[array.length - 1] = temp;
        timesShifted++;
    }
}
```

[For details](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/101056-shifting-array-elements-left/)